# SQL Server Snapshot replication - Failing to start the Publisher snapshot agent

Tags: sql-server, replication, azure-sql-managed-instance, snapshot-replication

I am trying to set up a Snapshot replication using an Azure SQL Managed Instance. While trying to see the Snapshot Agent status, I see this error. **Failed to connect to Azure Storage '' with OS error: 53.**

**Update : I fixed this error by setting up the Snapshot folder in this format : \\replstorage.file.core.windows.net\replshare**

However, when I fixed this error I get this new error.  **"Access to the path '\unc\XXXXXXXX-MANAGEDINSTAxxxxxxx_XXXXXXX_PUBLICATION\20200708132018' is denied."**

I followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems#error-5-when-you-mount-an-azure-file-share) and made sure that I I set the  Secure transfer required as Disabled, and Allow access from all networks is enabled, and Azure Active Directory Domain Services is disabled in the storage account settngs in the Azure Portal. Still the error remains the same.

Can anybody guide me to find out the problem ?

Comment: This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/replication-between-two-instances-configure-tutorial#requirements

Comment: @SqlWorldWide Thanks, I would try these out.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide I have fixed this error when I set the snapshot folder in the form \\replstorage.file.core.windows.net\replshare. but, now I get this error - "Access to the path '\unc\XXXXXXXX-MANAGEDINSTAxxxxxxx_XXXXXXX_PUBLICATION\20200708132018\' is denied."

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/96218e7a-36ef-4dcf-95f0-82f0ef0d4768/access-denied-error-when-trying-to-mount-azure-storage-as-network-drive?forum=windowsazuredata

Comment: @SqlWorldWide Updated the question